# Add sort order options to custom Wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is my custom loop, I need to add a sorting option and after hours of digging I cannot find a solution.

```
<ul class="acapellas row">
                <?php   
                    $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
                        'post_type' => 'acapella',
                        'posts_per_page' => 10,
                        'paged' => $paged,
                        'orderby' => 'date'
                    )); 
                ?>
                <?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
                <?php if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>


                    <li class="post-<?php the_ID(); ?> col-md-6">
                        <div class="wrap"> 

                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h2>

                            <?php if(pmpro_hasMembershipLevel($level_id)) { ?>

                            <?php the_content(); ?>

                            <?php } else { ?>

                            <div class="pro-player">
                                <div class="upgrade">
                                    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/pro" >Upgrade to unlock</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <?php } ?>

                            <a class="download left" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Download</a>

                            <span class="list-date right">First added: <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></span><br>

                           <?php
                            global $post;
                            $post_type            = get_post_type(get_the_ID());
                            $post_type_taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post_type);

                            if (!empty($post_type_taxonomies)) {

                                echo '<ul class="details">';

                                foreach ($post_type_taxonomies as $taxonomy) {

                                    $terms = get_the_term_list(get_the_ID(), $taxonomy, '', '</li><li>', '');


                                    if ($terms) {
                                        echo '<li>' . $terms . '</li>';
                                    }
                                }

                                echo '</ul>';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use both `orderby` and `order`, like so:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'acapella',
     'posts_per_page' => 10,
     'paged' => $paged,
     'orderby' => 'date',
     'order' => 'asc'
 ));
```